# How to describe files using mask in Spring Boot Test @Sql annotation?

Tags: java, sql, spring, testing

There is @Sql annotation which is placed under @Test methods to execute Sql scripts.

Ordinary usage:

```
    @Sql(scripts = "/folder/my_favourite_script.sql")
    @Test
```

Let's imagine there are 1000 sql files in the folder and I would like to execute all of them at once. How to describe the files using mask?

Desired result:

```
    @Sql(scripts = "/folder/*.sql")
    @Test
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work this way:

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException:
> **Cannot read SQL script from class path resource** [folder/*.sql]; nested
> exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
> [folder/*.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: What database are you using for your tests?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: @mrkachariker what is the relative of that question to the problem ?
@mvn.2047 where are those files located, /resources ? if not, can you move those to `src/main/resources` and then retry.

Comment: @muhammedozbilici Correct, it is in ```src/test/resources```. Doesn't work :(

Comment: @mvn.2047 then, can you try it like this `@Sql(scripts={"classpath:data.sql"})`

Comment: @muhammedozbilici There is no problem to execute a single file. The question is about to execute a lot of files using mask (*).

Comment: @mvn.2047 oov, sorry. couldn't find with sql annotation but I think you can use datasource definitions like : `spring.datasource.data=/META-INF/sql/init-*.sql
spring.datasource.schema=/META-INF/sql/schema-*.sql`

Comment: @muhammedozbilici No, it doesn't work this way. That's why I have opened a question. I have described it in the post. Anyway, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Sql` annotation (as well as `@SqlGroup` which takes an array of `@Sql`) you cannot pass a file mask and have it handled. AFIK there is no such annotation offered by Spring with the purpose of loading SQL files.

Therefore, your options are:

1. **PostgreSQL**: As already said, you cannot include files through masking with any existing annotations. However, [check this link out](https://mubasil-bokhari.medium.com/execute-sql-script-in-spring-boot-30636884a932) to learn how to do it imperatively. Basically, you have to add an `@Autowired DataSource ds` and execute the scripts by calling operations on it instead of the annotation magic... This way you can also add file mask logic for any particular folder.
2. **H2**: [runscript](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#runscript) command if you are using H2 for your test db. You would use this by creating an .sql (let's call it scripts.sql) file in your resources with content such as:

   ```
   RUNSCRIPT FROM 'file1.sql';
   RUNSCRIPT FROM 'file2.sql';
   etc...
   ```

   and then include only said file with the annotation like so: `@Sql("scripts.sql")`

Comment: It is very supportive answer. Appreciate your efforts.